# MySQL mirroring on EC2

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, rds

I'm running two MySQL server one on production and one on staging, both are EC2 Instance.
The same way i have two MySQL RDS Instances parallel to the production and staging.
Here want i wanted to do.
I would like to mirror the production database to the development server every few hours,
for 1. backup, 2. to run new features against the latest database changes.
I didn't find much information regarding this issue, can anyone help?
Thanks.

Additional information:
i'm running nginx on linux server, with php backend.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running on RDS, you have two options.

1. Snapshot and restore your instance. You can automate this, but the time it make take more time the larger the DB is. Your endpoint will probably change too.
2. Dump the database from production, reload into development.

Comment: can i do it automatically with a stored procedure or background task? can you reference me to it?

Comment: You should be able to do in both cases. You will need to run the automation from another instance however.